# Showing problems in '<' and '>' symbols in php

Tags: php, sms, symbols

I have a string

```
$string = "test<String>";
```

but when i make

```
echo $string;
```

it shows:

```
testString
```

and when I send the $string to mobile as SMS it shows

```
&lt;testString&gt;
```

How can I show "test<String>" with < and > symbol ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you serving it as HTML to a browser?  And what do you mean by "send to mobile as SMS"?  Using what library?

Comment: @fean: this isn't a PHP issue at all.  Rather it's an issue of the end-client and how they parse/display text.

Comment: See [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).  Escape the string with that when you echo it and it should display properly.

Comment: @ Oli: I'm using an SMS api where only the return value shows as SMS

Comment: @ drew010: I've tred htmlspecialchars. But for SMS it shows the converted encoded characters directly, without decoding it as symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any solution for mobile sms tag, so for mobile i've used ( and ) instead of < and > for serving purpose temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

You basically do it in reverse.

```
&lt;String&gt;
```

this will tell html to output the less than and greater than characters.

This should help you out
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$string = "test<string>";
$string = htmlspecialchars($string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Sorry, it remains same for SMS,

Comment: If the device displaying the sms does not decode the special char it should diplay test&lt;String&gt; if you used the htmlspecialchars function. However if you did not use the function it should display test<String>.If not, i agree with what bob-the-destroyer said it is not a php issue, maybe your device or sms API.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what SMS-api you are using, maybe you have to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the string before you send it to the api.